# What does it look like on the device when you build and run Android yourself?

Tags: android-source

I just followed the instructions on source.android.com for building Android from source.  The build appeared to succeed, and it generated .img files which I fastbooted onto a device.

I started up the device, and got a black screen.

I can "adb shell" into the device and cd around and stuff, but nothing shows on the screen.

Usually, a black screen tells me something is wrong, but it's crossed my mind that maybe this time it's actually right, and the Android version one builds from source is a slim version without any of the bells and whistles, desktop with apps, browser, settings etc like the Android you get when you buy a phone.

My question: What normally shows on the screen when you build and run Android from source?

Comment: The display should definitely work, so there's something wrong with your build. It would help if the question indicated _what_ device you built. That aside, a common cause for a blank screen is that you didn't include the proprietary graphics libraries that need to be downloaded separately.

Comment: Thanks very much, I believe that answers my question.  For the record, I was building for a Nexus 7 "grouper".